# What is the best way to fix a list index out of range exception?

Tags: python

I have written this recursive code in Python:

```
def suma(i,l):
    if i == 0:
        return l[i]
    else:
        return suma(i-1,l)+l[i]
```

And whenever I call the function by `suma(3,[7,2,3])` and run it, I get this error message:

> List index out of range on line return suma(i-1,l)+l[i]

Comment: You go up to `l[3]`. This is out of range because lists are 0-indexed, i.e. the first element has index 0.

Comment: use `l[i-1]` instead every `[i]`

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to post the same code indentation that you're actually using either.

Comment: @TomKarzes Gotta love it. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm going to assume that the intent here is to recursively add the first `i` elements of `l` and return the result.  If so, here's a concise way to do so:

```
def suma(i,l):
    return 0 if i == 0 else suma(i-1,l)+l[i-1]
```

This is equivalent to:

```
def suma(i,l):
    if i == 0:
        return 0
    else
        return suma(i-1,l)+l[i-1]
```

Comment: You could reduce that to `return i and suma(i-1,l)+l[i-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

It's unorthodox, but you could just call your `suma()` function with the first argument reduced by 1:

```
>>> l = [7, 2, 3]
>>> suma(len(l)-1, l)
12
```

But it could be better written like this:

```
def suma(l):
    if len(l) > 1:
        return suma(l[:-1]) + l[-1]
    return l[0]

>>> suma([7,2,3])
12
>>> suma(range(1,11))
55
```

This has the advantage of not requiring the length of the list to be passed to the sum function at all - the length is always available using `len()`.